# Causative faire with a verb that takes à?

Tags: grammaire, constructions-causatives

For example:

> Nous faisons envoyer des fleurs à Fiona.

Does that mean

> we're having flowers sent *to* Fiona

or

> we're having Fiona send flowers?

Edit: I found a very thorough discussion of this problem in an old paper in The Modern Language Journal: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-4781.1944.tb03916.x/abstract

Comment: Both meanings are valid, it depends on the context.

Comment: I didn't even realize both meanings are correct, what comes in mind first is really the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les 2 sont possibles, mais le sens le plus évident est:

> We're having flowers sent to Fiona.

L'autre interprétation ne serait pas entièrement correcte en français (et en anglais) : *Fiona envoie des fleurs* est incomplet (à qui ?)

Elle nécessiterait un complément d'object indirect :

> We're having Fiona send flowers to ...

=>

> Nous faisons en sorte que Fiona envoie des fleurs à ...